# Django 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making queries to get the total number of apples by month. Now I want retrieve and print the data of `total_apple`.

```
fruits= Fruits.objects\
        .annotate(month = TruncMonth('sold_date'))\
        .values('month')\
        .annotate(total_apple=Sum('apple'))\
        .order_by('-month')
```

I've tried many ways to print it but returned an error.

I've tried:

1)

```
total_apple= fruits['total_apple']
print(total_apple)
```

2)

```
context['total_apple'] = total_apple
print(context)
```

An error returned: 
`No exception message supplied`

3)

```
print(fruits.total_apple)
```

Error returned: 
`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'total_apple'`

But when I tried `print(fruits)`, it returned queryset that contain the attributes that I want.

```
<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2018, 10, 1), 'total_apple': 1636}, {'month': datetime.date(2018, 9, 1), 'total_apple': 1658},.....>
```

Comment: As you can see returned object is a QuerySet so you have to iterate it to get attribute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fruits= Fruits.objects\
        .annotate(month = TruncMonth('sold_date'))\
        .values('month')\
        .annotate(total_apple=Sum('apple'))\
        .order_by('-month')
```

This query returns a list of object.
So you can iterate over `fruits` and print `fruit.total_apple`

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit['total_apple'])
```

`fruits` return QueryDict, so you need to access it's value by key like `total_apple`

below the query.

Also mention that if you want single result you can query like this

```
fruits= Fruits.objects\
            .annotate(month = TruncMonth('sold_date'))\
            .values('month')\
            .annotate(total_apple=Sum('apple'))\
            .order_by('-month').first()
```

Then `print(fruits.total_apple)`

Comment: I've tried the for loop, but still get the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'total_apple'`

Comment: What's your try?

Comment: I've tried this: `for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit.total_apple)`

Comment: Use `aggregate`  rather than `annotate`

Comment: Shouldn't be `annotate`? Because I want to get the data which is group by month. If i use `aggregate`, it will calculate values for entire queryset.

Comment: Yes, the data of `total_apples` is able to display, but it can't works in views.py

Comment: oh ya, it works! By the way, what's the difference between `fruit.total_apple` and `fruit['total_apple']` ?

Comment: Great! Mark it accepted. This may help other developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185769/discussion-between-shafikur-rahman-shaon-and-yvonne).

Answer (score 3):

`fruits` is a queryset and not a django model instance. Try indexing the `fruits` queryset like this:

```
fruits[0].total_apple
```

**UPDATE**

Since the accepted answer has `.values` in it, `fruits[0]['total_apple']` will work fine instead of `fruits[0].total_apple`. `values()` converts each object in your queryset into a `dict`.

Comment: Correct! The result is a queryset. He must get the first or loop through all elements to access total_apple

Comment: I still get the `error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'total_apple'`

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out to see why you're still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use python shell to test the ideas. This example clearly show the way to get desired output:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.all()
>>> user
<QuerySet [<User: bg>, <User: test>]>
>>> user.all()
<QuerySet [<User: bg>, <User: test>]>
>>> user[0]
<User: bg>
>>> user[1].username #this is the way to get theyou need to do
'test'
>>> user[1].password
'pbkdf2_sha256$100000$nJzzPRnFyNvq$MUmPTnzCKJRqxHskU5OpUtFIgMwY5Ap8fPMQMm4fUFQ
```

In your case, you can do a loop to print all the object's `total_apple`

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit.total_apple)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> for user in users:
...    print(user.username)
...    
bg
test
```

Comment: I've tried the for loop, but still get the error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'total_apple'